# Is it possible to build QGIS with qt5 without changing the code?

Tags: qgis

I wish to build QGIS using qt5. 
As told here ([Can I use QGIS with Qt5?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/can-i-use-qgis-with-qt5)) it is possible with GIS 2.10.

So i've loaded sources from here git://github.com/qgis/QGIS.git and switched to remotes/origin/release-2_10 branch.

During the compile process i've got lots of errors.

The first is:

```
.../QGIS/src/core/geometry/qgsgeometry.cpp: In member function ‘void QgsGeometry::detach(bool)’:
.../QGIS/src/core/geometry/qgsgeometry.cpp:110:17: error: no match for ‘operator>’ in ‘((QgsGeometry*)this)->QgsGeometry::d->QgsGeometryPrivate::ref > 1’
```

Any suggestions? 
Is it realy possible to build QGis using qt5, without changing code?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile QGIS today with Qt5 without code change (answer already at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/160074/638) but you will not have Python support.

Although it's possible to compile with QT5, the support is not official at the moment. You can see this [blog post about the QGIS 3.0 roadmap](http://anitagraser.com/2015/05/31/qgis-3-0-future-plans/) for more informations on future default support (exactly when?).

Comment: This answer simply contradicts the answer which is linked in the first line.

Comment: Okay. Is there any build instructions, cmake configuration, tutorial etc.?
I've got all dependencies satisfied, and configured cmake file, but qgis still fails to compile.

Comment: The best resources are probably still the information from the [pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1676)

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth citing the well hidden information from the [pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1676) that introduced Qt5 into QGIS here.

> **Disclaimer**
>
> Qt5 is not yet officially supported and while we are trying to keep the QGIS source code as compatible as possible, it can often be, that the current master development branch will not build against Qt5.
>
> Please also note that there has been no report yet about working python support. While this seems to be well possible, somebody will have to adjust some build scripts (cmake and python files) to actually prove it.

## Dependencies

Make sure you have the dependencies compiled and linked agains Qt5 also.
Most notably:

- QWT
- QScintilla2
- QWTPolar (optional - either compile it or disable it with `-DWITH_QWTPOLAR=FALSE`)

## Configure

We assume a directory structure with the source and build folders next to each other like

> ```
> $ ls dev/qgis/
> build <-- build directory (mkdir ...)
> QGIS  <-- source code (git clone ...)
> $ cd dev/qgis/build
> ```

**Start with a clean build directory** leftovers from previous Qt4 builds will prevent the build from completing successfully. Make sure to specify `-DENABLE_QT5` from the beginning

```
cmake -DENABLE_QT5=TRUE -DWITH_BINDINGS=FALSE -DWITH_INTERNAL_QWTPOLAR=FALSE ../QGIS
```

You may have to adapt the lib and include paths to manually built Qt5 dependencies (QWT, QScintilla) with a tool like

```
ccmake ../QGIS
```

## Build

Finally call

```
make
```

which of course can be parallelized as usual with the `-j[number of cores]` parameter

## Complete command listing

```
cd dev/qgis/QGIS
mkdir ../build
cd ../build
cmake -DENABLE_QT5=TRUE -DWITH_BINDINGS=FALSE -DWITH_INTERNAL_QWTPOLAR=FALSE ../QGIS
ccmake ../QGIS
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthias! 

But now the problem occurs at linkage time. 


/usr/bin/ld: ../../output/bin/qgis: hidden symbol `_ZN6QDebugD1Ev' in /home/albert/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5UiTools.a(abstractformbuilder.o) is referenced by DSO /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value 

Actually i have no good idea what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Well... i did it.
The problem was that the kubuntu have its own qt libs and headers (qt4 version). cmake have used it despite configuration options. 
I had to declare lots of macro definitions such as QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR, QT_QT_LIBRARY.

I think that problem is somewhere in ./cmake/modules/ECMQt4To5Porting.cmake file.

Thank you all for your support!

Comment: Did you start with a clean build directory as indicated in my post?

Comment: Yes. I've used the folowing sequence of commands (from QGIS root dir):
    
    mkdir build;
    cd build;
    ccmake ..;
    make;
    
In that case linker used both qt5 and qt4 libraries.
If it would be helpfull I can repeat build procedure later and post listings.

Comment: The problem is the initial call to `ccmake` in the new build dir without explicitly specifying `-DENABLE_QT5=TRUE`. This will cause cmake to pickup Qt4 and once the cmake cache is populated with Qt4 values it's really hard to clean it all.

Comment: I updated my original post to include a listing at the bottom.