# Would a QGIS qt5 build use qt5's OpenGL rendering capabilities?

Tags: qgis, qt

Related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163272/is-it-possible-to-build-qgis-with-qt5-without-changing-the-code/163581), I am considering building QGIS with qt5 (caveats acknowledged) in order to improve rendering speed with qt5's OpenGL support. Before I attempt this I need to know whether QGIS (2.8/2.10) built this way would actually use qt5's OpenGL capabilities for improved rendering.

Can anyone confirm this and perhaps provide a guide as to the degree of rendering performance increase one may expect over a standard qt4 build (obviously context dependant, but order of magnitude indication would be nice)

Comment: You are almost certainly underestimating the amount of work to port an application from Qt4 to Qt5. Even if you managed that, it's unlikely it would automatically make use of alternate rendering techniques.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with "Qt5's OpenGL capabilities"? I.e. what leads to your assumption that existing implementations should make more use of OpenGL when using Qt5?