# Installing QGIS 2.14.9-Essen with Qt 5.6.1 on RHEL7 (64-bit)

Tags: qgis, installation, qt, 64bit, red-hat

1. I have installed RHEL7
2. Installed qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.2.run
3. Installed qgis-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm with other dependencies as follows:

   ```
   1. qgis-2.14.9-1.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.1. gpsbabel-1.5.0-2.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.1.1. shapelib-1.3.0-2.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.2. qtwebkit-2.3.4-6.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.2.1. glib2-2.46.2-4.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3. gdal-libs-1.11.4-1.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3.1. CharLS-1.0-5.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3.2. armadillo-4.320.0-1.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3.2.1. arpack-3.1.3-2.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3.2.1.1. atlas-3.10.1-10.el7 RPM for x86_64
   1.3.2.2. blas-3.4.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.2.3. lapack-3.4.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.3. cfitsio-3.370-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.4. libdap-3.13.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.5. freexl-1.0.0f-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.6. geos-3.4.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.7. libgeotiff-1.2.5-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.7.1. proj-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.8. libgta-1.0.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.9. netcdf-4.3.3.1-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.10. unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.11. ogdi-3.2.0-0.19.beta2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.12. openjpeg2-2.1.0-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.13. poppler-0.26.5-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.3.14. xerces-c-3.1.1-8.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
   1.4. gsl-1.15-13.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.5. qextserialport-1.2-0.6.beta2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.6. qscintilla-2.8-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.7. qwt-6.1.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.8. qwtpolar-1.1.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.9. spatialindex-1.8.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   1.10. libspatialite-4.1.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   ```
4. Installed qgis-devel-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm with dependencies tree as follows:

   ```
   2.qgis-devel-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1. qgis-server-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.1. fcgi-2.4.0-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2. qgis-python-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.1. gdal-python-1.11.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.1.1. numpy-1.7.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.1.1.1. python-nose-1.3.0-3.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.1. python-OWSLib-0.9.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.2. python-httplib2-0.7.7-3.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.3. python-jinja2-2.7.2-2.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.3.1. python-babel-0.9.6-8.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.3.2. python-markupsafe-0.11-10.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.4. python-matplotlib-1.2.0-15.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.4.1. dvipng-1.11-3.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.4.1.1. kpathsea-2007-60.el6_7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.4.1.2. t1lib-5.1.2-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.4.2. agg-2.5-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.5. python-psycopg2-2.5.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.6. python-pygments-1.4-9.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.6.1. python2-pillow-4.0.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.2.6.1.1. python2-olefile-0.44-1.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.1.2.6.1.2. libimagequant-2.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.1.3. mod_fcgid-2.3.9-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2. qgis-grass-2.14.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1. grass-6.4.4-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.1. motif-2.3.4-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.1.1. libXp-1.0.2-2.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.1.2. xorg-x11-xbitmaps-1.1.1-6.el7.noarch.rpm
   2.2.1.2. fftw2-2.1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.3. grass-libs-6.4.4-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.4. proj-epsg-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.5. proj-nad-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.6. wxGTK-gl-2.8.12-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.6.1. wxBase-2.8.12-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.6.2. wxGTK-2.8.12-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.7. wxPython-2.8.12.0-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
   2.2.1.7.1. wxGTK-media-2.8.12-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
   ```

Now I started QGIS Desktop from application menu then at the start Error appears as

```
 "Couldn't load plugin 'processing'".
```

I Ignored the error opened Qt and written first program to test QGIS

.pro is here

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
QT += xml
TARGET = temp2
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS  +=
FORMS    +=
LIBS += -L/usr/lib64 -lqgis_core
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qgis
DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT=""
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT=""
```

main.cpp is here :

```
#include <qgsapplication.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    return app.exec();
}
```

After build on Run

```
"the program has unexpectedly finished".
```

What mistake I have committed? How to solve it?

Comment: I have invested 2 weeks in search for the solution but failed. pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS 2.xx python plugins depends on PyQT4 - so you need Qt4. Qt5 only let you use QGIS without python and is experimental. 
The future QGIS 3 will use PyQt5 and python3. See details about QGIS 3 in [blogpost](http://blog.qgis.org/2016/02/10/qgis-3-0-plans/).

Comment: Thank you. but i haven't written anything related to python in my program still it is crashing ?

Comment: and i found while searching that many of us using qgis with Qt5 e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/160074/93066

Comment: Processing is python plugin, so you need disable build python support. Also your link about QGIS 2.18, which maybe more friendly with Qt5.

Comment: now I have removed qt5 and installed qt4.7.4 with qt creator 2.3.1 then building same program as above then it shows following errors "undefined reference to QMutex::unlockInternal()", "undefined reference to QMutex::lockInternal()", "undefined reference to QImage::fill(Qt::GlobalColor)", etc. Is there any solution to this problem ??

Comment: This is not the same error. You previously wrote: "the program has unexpectedly finished". Now you have compile error, as compiler don't find qtcore library.

Comment: So what to do...to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Ask another question with appropriate topic and full details - library and compiler versions, system paths and environment, your build stpes etc. Here it looks like offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

I have sloved "Couldn't load plugin 'processing'" problem (On RHEL7.1)  as follows:

```
1. # wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
2. # sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-7*.rpm
3. # sudo yum install epel-release
4. # sudo yum install dnf
5. # sudo yum install python-pip
6. # CFLAGS=-I/usr/include pip install pyspatialite
```

Done.